# Error 1004 Method 'Protect' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to protect my sheets again after running a macro. It comes up with an `Run-time error 1004 Method 'Protect' of object '_Worksheet' failed`. All sheets are unprotected before running this script. If they are protected on beforehand the fail still come.

I have tried changing `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`. When I did this I could run `ProtectAll` fine by it self. Running the whole code makes the problem.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const yourPassword As String = "MyPassWord"

Sub ButtonClick()

UnprotectAll

MyMainRutineCall

ProtectAll

End Sub
Sub MyMainRutineCall()

Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim lOver As Long
Dim ary
Dim a As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandler


Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

strName = "PDF" _
          & " - " & wsA.Range("G61").Value _

'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

If bFileExists(strPathFile) Then
  lOver = MsgBox("Overwrite existing file?", _
    vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "File Exists")
  If lOver <> vbYes Then
    'user can enter name and
    ' select folder for file
    myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
      (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
          FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
          Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")
    If myFile <> "False" Then
      strPathFile = myFile
    Else
      GoTo exitHandler
    End If
  End If
End If

'Select sheets to use
ary = Array(Sheet7.Name, Sheet3.Name)

For Each a In ary
    Sheets(a).Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Next a

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ary).Select

'export to PDF in current folder
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=strPathFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

'confirmation message with file info
MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
  & vbCrLf _
  & strPathFile

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler

End Sub

Sub UnprotectAll()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
    Next sh
End Sub

Sub ProtectAll()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Protect Password:=yourPassword
    Next sh
End Sub
```

The things that is buggy is `sh.Protect Password:=yourPassword`

Comment: Maybe that particular sheet isn't a worksheet. Are there any diagram-sheets in your workbook? Try to replace `worksheets` with `sheets`.

Comment: Have you explored `UserInterfaceOnly` option when protecting your worksheet?

Comment: Does it work if you comment out or delete the line  `MyMainRutineCall`? If it runs, then you must include the code of `MyMainRutineCall` in your question.

Comment: I have updated with `MyMainRutineCall`

Comment: @Horst It has to be worksheets. It cannot work with sheets.

Comment: @SimonJ Where is your button located (which workbook and worksheet)? • Note that `If myFile <> "False" Then` must be `If myFile <> False Then` because `GetSaveAsFilename` returns a `boolean` type `False` if cancel is pressed not a `string`.

Comment: @Zac What a great solution! It seems to work now.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The button is located in none of the pages that should be printed. So in another sheet.

Comment: @SimonJ In the same workbook? Then replace all your `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` it is much more reliable. Avoid `ActiveWorkbook` unless you are coding an add-in or something similar. • Is this solved now?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ YEs it is solved now :) Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue seemed to be

```
If myFile <> "False" Then
```

which should be

```
If myFile <> False Then
```

because the [Application.GetSaveAsFilename method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename) returns either a file name as `Variant/String` or a `False` as `Variant/Boolean`. But not a string `"False"`.

So my recommendation is also to use `ThisWorkbook` in some more places to make it more reliable:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const yourPassword As String = "MyPassWord"

Sub ButtonClick()

    UnprotectAll

    MyMainRutineCall

    ProtectAll

End Sub

Sub MyMainRutineCall()
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim wbA As Workbook
    Set wbA = ThisWorkbook

    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Set wsA = wbA.ActiveSheet

    'get active workbook folder, if saved
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = IIf(wbA.path = vbNullString, Application.DefaultFilePath, wbA.path) & Application.PathSeparator

    Dim strName As String
    strName = "PDF" & " - " & wsA.Range("G61").Value

    'create default name for savng file
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = strName & ".pdf"

    Dim strPathFile As String
    strPathFile = strPath & strFile

    If bFileExists(strPathFile) Then
        If MsgBox("Overwrite existing file?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "File Exists") <> vbYes Then
            ' user can enter name and
            ' select folder for file
            Dim myFile As Variant
            myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
                InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
                FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
                Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")
            If myFile <> False Then
                strPathFile = myFile
            Else
                GoTo exitHandler
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'Select sheets to use
    Dim ary() As Variant
    ary = Array(Sheet7.Name, Sheet3.Name)

    Dim a As Variant
    For Each a In ary
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(a).Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Next a

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ary).Select

    'export to PDF in current folder
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strPathFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " & vbCrLf & strPathFile

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub


Sub UnprotectAll()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
    Next sh
End Sub


Sub ProtectAll()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Protect Password:=yourPassword
    Next sh
End Sub
```